# Sails API - How to avoid creating new filter for every new field added to database

Tags: node.js, api

Title says it, Is there any way to avoid creating new filter for every new field added to the database if the field should be available for filtering purpose from client side/front end application.
This is one problem I notice that has been bugging me as I have to create a new filter every single time if a new field is added to the db.

database: mysql

sample code below:

```
function (req, res) {
  var params = req.params(); // get all params from request URI in JSON format
  var filter = {};
  if(params.name){
    filter.name = { contains: params.name };
  }

  // ... and so on for other fields.
  // this is where the part it is getting annoying
  // as if there's a new field added, we have to
  // add more and more code

  Model.find(filter).exec(function (err, records) {
    // handle error and send response back
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your question? which database you are using? where filter is used?

Comment: @XihuaDuan is it more clear to understand?

Comment: I believe by properly using Object.keys(), you can come out a concise and neat solution.

Comment: I have posted my sample code for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Here comes my code snippet for your reference:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(params)) {
   filter[key] = {contains: params[key]};
}
```